# Local Homeomorphisms: Characterization

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, definition

**Problem**

Consider for simplicity a surjection $F:X\to Y$.

Are these characterizations of local homeomorphisms equivalent:
$$\forall x\in X:\exists U_x\in\mathcal{T}_X, V_y\in\mathcal{T}_Y:\quad U_x\cong V_y\quad (F(x)=y)$$
$$\forall y\in Y:\exists U_x\in\mathcal{T}_X, V_y\in\mathcal{T}_Y:\quad U_x\cong V_y\quad (F(x)=y)$$
*(I'm asking as usually this is handled rather sloppy.)*

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant as summary. For more informations see:

- [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)
- [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762)

*(The second especially reveals the opinion of the community!)*

Comment: As far as educating your readers is concerned, pointing to any meta thread surrounding the Makoto Kato drama is probably not the best move

Comment: @EricStucky: Hmm, yes that might give a wrong impression... So for those who don't know: He was rather suspended for rude behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inclusion**

The former implies the latter as:
$$y=F(x)\implies U_x\cong V_y$$
*(That is one can choose any preimage.)*

**Counterexample**

Consider the wrap of the real line onto the dotted circle:
$$F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{S}\setminus\{1\}:\quad F(\varphi=0):=-1,F(\varphi\neq0):=e^{i\varphi}$$
Then only the ladder holds true since:
$$F(\pi-\varepsilon,\pi+\varepsilon)\cong(\pi-\varepsilon,\pi+\varepsilon)\quad(\varepsilon\leq\pi)$$
$$F(0-\varepsilon,0+\varepsilon)\ncong(0-\varepsilon,0+\varepsilon)\quad(\varepsilon\leq\pi)$$
*(That is one may have to choose specific preimage.)*

**Perspective**

Note that a covering handles precisely this discrepancy!